# Ubuntu apt update error `Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)`

Tags: apt, 18.04, updates

On my Ubuntu 18.04LTS vm I run the command `apt update` and whilst running I get the following output:

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/minitube$ LANG=C sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu bionic InRelease                       
Hit:3 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                           
Get:4 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]        
Get:5 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Fetched 252 kB in 1s (345 kB/s)                              
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Reading package lists... Done
```

And I want to fix the cause of the following error message:

```
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

Do you know how to do that?

I did restart the `dbus` deamon via:

```
sudo service dbus restart
```

And I get the following message:

```
Μαρ 24 19:50:39 user-VirtualBox dbus-daemon[581]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service' requested by ':1.169' (uid=0 pid=20405 comm="/usr/bin/gdbus 
Μαρ 24 19:51:04 user-VirtualBox dbus-daemon[581]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Μαρ 24 19:51:35 user-VirtualBox dbus-daemon[581]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service' requested by ':1.171' (uid=0 pid=22736 comm="/usr/bin/gdbus 
Μαρ 24 19:52:00 user-VirtualBox dbus-daemon[581]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Μαρ 24 19:59:32 user-VirtualBox dbus-daemon[581]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service' requested by ':1.174' (uid=0 pid=1727 comm="/usr/bin/gdbus c
Μαρ 24 19:59:57 user-VirtualBox dbus-daemon[581]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Μαρ 24 20:01:40 user-VirtualBox dbus-daemon[581]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service' requested by ':1.176' (uid=0 pid=6556 comm="/usr/bin/gdbus c
Μαρ 24 20:02:05 user-VirtualBox dbus-daemon[581]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Μαρ 24 20:10:30 user-VirtualBox dbus-daemon[581]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service' requested by ':1.110' (uid=1000 pid=2814 comm="/usr/bin/gnom
Μαρ 24 20:10:55 user-VirtualBox dbus-daemon[581]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

Comment: Restarting systemd might help.

Comment: I placed some info on restarting the service.

Comment: In my case, I was tring purge dbus and reinstalling it. Then I found dbus have unmet dependencies `fish` , then I purged `fish` and found systemd worked again.  For people with same problem, purge and reinstall dbus could be a solution, or remove unmet dependencies `fish`.